# Sharpen a part of a image based on a target image with arUco markers

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, camera, aruco

I'm trying to detect as many arUco markers as possible around a screen, but due to the limitations of the camera it sometimes only detects 3-4 markers when the maximum of markers is 16.

So if I know the coordinates of one marker, is it possible to sharpen the image to detect the rest of the markers based on a reference image? It would be cool if it's possible to do it in OpenCV and Python which are the tools that I'm currently using.

[image: Camera image]

[image: Reference image]

I have not tried anything yet because I can't find anything similar online about this topic.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you control the taking of the photo, you might consider better controlling the room lighting and positioning the camera further away from the screen but zooming the lens to a longer focal length.